# drawUnderStatusBar causing tab bar bottom cut off React native navigation on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I set `drawUnderStatusBar: true` to set status bar transparent, this causing tab bar bottom cut off a half.
The issue is on Android because `drawUnderStatusBar` is Android prop only.
If set it to false, tab bar would show fine.

[image]

Steps to Reproduce:

push a screen with `drawUnderStatusBar: true` and pop (to main screen with tab bar).

Environment:

```
React Native Navigation version: 1.1.334
React Native version: 0.55
Platform: Android
Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): Nexus 6, Android 7.1.1, debug
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once.
I fixed it by adding `style={Stylesheet.absoluteFill}` to the main container and it solved the issue.